# MSBuild or NAnt or Rake tasks for Wise Installation Studio

Tags: build, installation, wise

Does anyone know of any MSBuild or NAnt tasks for controlling Wise Installation Studio?

I know, I should probably just use WiX but my current project is already in Wise and all I need to automate is updating of a product code, the upgrade section and a few bits of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using CruiseControl.NET - this could be adapted for use in a Nant-only solution if desired.  I call wfwi.exe which is included in the Wise installation and is meant for command line access ([here's the Wise installer manual which contains instructions for wfwi.exe](http://www.altiris.com/upload/windowsinstallereditor_007.pdf)).  Here's a snippet from my ccnet.config:

```
<!-- build installers -->

<exec>
<executable>C:\Path\To\WiseWrapper.bat</executable>
<buildArgs>"C:\Path\To\wfwi.exe" "C:\Path\To\Output.wsi" /c /p /s</buildArgs>
</exec>

<!-- build installer exes -->

<exec>
<executable>C:\Path\To\Wise32.exe</executable>
<buildArgs>/c /s C:\Path\To\Your.wse</buildArgs>
</exec>
```

And the WiseWrapper.bat allows the installer ProductVersion to be updated using the CC.NET build label.  The entire contents of WiseWrapper.bat is:

```
%1 %2 %3 %4 ProductVersion=%CCNetLabel% %5
```